# Convert Audio to Base64 string in iOS + Swift

Tags: ios, swift, base64

```
var fileLocation = NSString(string:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "mp3")!)
let plainData = fileLocation(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
println(base64String!)
```

Comment: Do you have any question? Above code is working?

Comment: No, it's not working. How can I do it? I want to sent audio file to web service.

Comment: `let plainData = fileLocation(NSUTF8StringEncoding)` is wrong. Use this `let plainData = fileLocation.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

Comment: I tried, but it is not working. I just want to convert audio to base64. I can convert image file, but I did not convert audio file.

Comment: So what difficulties you face. Edit your question with the details :what output or crash or unexpected things happens when you run your code.

Comment: I know that this way is wrong. This code only convert file path. I do not want to file path, I want to convert file :)

Comment: Output is file path. Not file. L1VzZXJzL0dPS0hBTi9MaWJyYXJ5L0RldmVsb3Blci9Db3JlU2ltdWxhdG9yL0RldmljZXMvQzY2Mzc0NDYtREJGMi00N0FGLTkwNzMtRjk4MEFGQzEyQ0JFL2RhdGEvQ29udGFpbmVycy9CdW5kbGUvQXBwbGljYXRpb24vQUQzMERFMkMtRDcwOC00OUNDLThGRkQtRjIwQUM4OTIxMTAxL2NvY3Vrb25tdWF5ZW5lLmFwcC9ha2NlbnQubXAz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get `NSData` from the location of your file, which is you missing here. Check below code:

```
var error: NSError?

var fileLocation = NSString(string:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "mp3")!)
let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: fileLocation, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &error)

let base64String = fileData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
println(base64String!)
```

Here you can get `NSData` of audio file (whatever file format is) and then convert this data to base64.