# base64 String to Audio mp3 in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, base64, decode

I have an base64 string and want to convert it into mp3 audio file.

```
var audioData = Data(base64Encoded: strBase64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
print(audioData)
```

It always returns nil.

Comment: is your string a valid base64 string? because `Data(base64Encoded:)` is a failable initializer and thats why it only retruns nil if your Input is not suitable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26992565/1675954

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43743498/1675954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let base64String : String = "some sample base64"
let audioData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)

if audioData != nil {
  if let audData = audioData {
    self.playAudio(audioData: audData)
  }
}

func playAudio(audioData : Data) {
  let filename = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("output.mp3")
  do {
    try audioData.write(to: filename, options: .atomicWrite)
    do {
      audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: filename)
      guard let player = audioPlayer else { return }
      player.prepareToPlay()
      player.play()
    } catch let error {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
  } catch {
  }
}
```